# How to fix "Multiple methods named 'reload' found with mismatched result, parameter type or attributes..."

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-ios

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6PNm.png)I'm compiling a react-native project.
I'm facing a error of "Multiple methods named 'reload' found with mismatched result, parameter type or attributes...".

```
- (void)selectDevMenuItemWithKey:(NSString *)key onBridge:(id)bridge
{
  RCTAssertMainQueue();
  RCTDevSettings *devSettings = [self _moduleInstanceForBridge:bridge named:@"DevSettings"];
  if ([key isEqualToString:@"dev-reload"]) {
    [bridge reload];
  } else if ([key isEqualToString:@"dev-remote-debug"]) {
    devSettings.isDebuggingRemotely = !devSettings.isDebuggingRemotely;
  } else if ([key isEqualToString:@"dev-live-reload"]) {
```

external information:

react-native for sdkVersion 27.0.0....
Pre-downloading: `ExpoKit` from `http://github.com/expo/expo.git`, tag `ios/2.5.10`

I tried to change this "sdkVersion": "27.0.0" to "28.0.0"..."32.0.0" in app.json but got same error.

I didn't find solution ...